# Accessing bytes of an object

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I have an object that contains no public variables, but all it does is hold data (another companies API, not something I can change). They do supply me with the byte map, telling me what values are how long, and where they're located.

Where I am at a loss is how to access these fields. In university we did plenty with memcpy and such, but in CLI I doubt that's the right way to go about this...

What's the best way to extract bytes of information out of this object?

below is a simple psuedo code of what I would like to accomplish, I am just not sure the best way to do this syntactically. I am not very familiar with CLI and .Net and figure there's got to be a good way to go about this...

```
int GetSingleDataPoint(int LowestByte,int NumOfBytes, Object^ DataRecord)
Copy the NumOfBytes starting at DataRecord[LowestBytes] to a temporary integer
return temporary integer
```

if it matters at all in this discussion, the data is packed little endian, and contains signed and unsigned variables ranging from 1-4 bytes long.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects being provided are CLI objects then generally it is not appropriate to directly access the bytes. I believe it is possible using Marshalling, however it would be easier to just use reflection to access the private/protected members. For instance:

```
Object^ getFieldByName(Object^ obj, String^ name, Type^ t)
{
    return t->GetField(name, BindingFlags::Public | BindingFlags::NonPublic | BindingFlags::Instance)->GetValue(obj);
}
```

If it's a native object, just do the following (basically what you suggested in the question):

```
int GetSingleDataPoint(int LowestByte,int NumOfBytes, void* object)
{
    int result;
    size_t numBytes;

    numBytes = NumOfBytes;
    if(numBytes > sizeof(int))
        numBytes = sizeof(int);

    memcpy(&result, object+LowestByte, numBytes);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The object(DataRecord) is created from a COM library, I believe it is written in c++, from the documentation that I have read.

Comment: @fooOnYou Then I don't think it's appropriate to use the ^ sign.

Comment: I have it in there currently and am able to compile. I set a break point where the object shows up at the start of my method and I can see the bytes are all present and valid from the variable inspector in VS2012, but I am still not sure how to get them out. I am intrigued by the code you posted, but not familiar with what exactly it does, I will look into it and see if I can understand it and make it work.

Comment: I like the second piece of code, but I haven't written anything like it in CLI and I wasn't sure if that was accepted. I assume I must use #include "string.h" to get access to memcpy..?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what ^ (dis)allows, but my understanding is that it's only to be used for managed types (__gc, __value)

Comment: Yes, C++ CLI is C++ with extensions to allow using managed types (.net). So you can do anything you can in C++ plus .net stuff.

Comment: Sounds good, I will play with this on Monday (leaving work now, will accept as solution once/if I get it working) and I will get back to you with the results then! I appreciate you helping me out, small company means it's hard to get the support on some of the 'smaller' things and concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is using C++ native code inside .NET project and use lovely `memcpy` or even type cast (that is even faster) for example

```
int n1 = * (unsigned char*) (DataRecord + LowestBytes);
int n2 = * (int16_t*) (DataRecord + LowestBytes);
int n4 = * (int32_t*) (DataRecord + LowestBytes);
```

Since in .NET you must use `Marshal` and since your class is a native C++ class it's something like hell!!